# Calling variable MvxCommand(s) from custom CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, xamarin, uicollectionviewcell, mvvmcross

I've been banging my head against this for two days now working with mvvmcross, and having never worked with iOS before I think there's just something I don't understand.

I created my main menu with a UICollectionView in a two-column 3-row grid, each item representing a different location the user can go to on tap. I can override "ItemSelected" from the UICollectionViewSource, but I can't access the actual ViewModel without passing a reference of it into the source on creation....which doesnt feel like the right way to do it to me.

```
 [MvxRootPresentation(WrapInNavigationController = true)]
    public partial class MainPageView : MvxViewController

    {

    private MenuCollectionSource _menuCollectionSource;
    List<MainMenuItem> menuItems;

    public MainPageViewModel VM
    {
        get { return DataContext as MainPageViewModel; }
    }

    private void SetupMenuCollectionView()
    {
    ......

        collectionView.RegisterNibForCell(MainMenuCollectionViewCell.Nib, MainMenuCollectionViewCell.Key);
        MainMenuItem.Init(menuItems);
        _menuCollectionSource = new MenuCollectionSource(collectionView, MainMenuCollectionViewCell.Key, menuItems);
        _menuCollectionSource.VM = VM; <----doesnt seem right.
        collectionView.Source = _menuCollectionSource;

    public class MenuCollectionSource : MvxCollectionViewSource
    {

        private UICollectionView _collectionView;
        public List<MainMenuItem> Items { get; set; }

        private MainPageViewModel _vm;
        public MainPageViewModel VM
        {
            get { return _vm; }
            set { _vm = value; }
        }

    }
```

With this method I can override ItemSelected in the ViewSource, and the do something like

```
( Cell is touched -> 
Depending on cell enum/cell# - >
vm.NavigateToCorrectPage())
```

While this method works, I don't think its the correct way to handle this situation.
So then my next thought was to bind the source like like...(may not be 100%, trying to remember in my head)

```
set.CreateBinding(_menuCollectionSource) .For(s => s.SelectedCommand) .To(vm => vm.NavigateTo) .CommandParameter(_menuCollectionSource.SelectedItem)
```

But no matter what I tried, the passed param was always null as if the selected item was never set or the command was being called before it was set.

My CollectionViewCell class is pretty basic

```
 public enum NavigationLocation
    {
    Search Database,
    Lists,
    etc....
    }
    public partial class MainMenuCollectionViewCell : MvxCollectionViewCell
    {
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("MainMenuCollectionViewCell");
    public static readonly UINib Nib;

        public string MainMenuLabel
        { get { return mainMenuLabel.Text; } }

        public int MainMenuIndexNumber
        { get; set; }

        protected MainMenuCollectionViewCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {

        }

        static MainMenuCollectionViewCell()
        {
            Nib = UINib.FromName("MainMenuCollectionViewCell",  NSBundle.MainBundle);
        }

        public static MainMenuCollectionViewCell Create()

        {
            NSArray topLevelObjects = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("MainMenuCollectionViewCell", null, null);
            MainMenuCollectionViewCell cell = Runtime.GetNSObject(topLevelObjects.ValueAt(0)) as MainMenuCollectionViewCell;
            return cell;
        }

        internal void BindData(string label, string iconBundleName)
        {
             mainMenuLabel.Text = label;
            mainMenuImage.Image = UIImage.FromBundle(iconBundleName);

        }
    }
```

No binding I've tried in the cell class has actually worked, even adding a UITapGestureRecognizer on creation caused a crash on actual tap. I've run out of ideas, does anyone know what I'm not understanding or missing to actually implement

```
( Cell is touched -> 
GetCellMenuType - >
CallCorrectCommandFromViewModel)
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: I tried the implementation you suggested below, and got hit with a NullReferenceException at new MvxCommand<Ios.MainMenuCollectionViewCellViewModel>((selectedItem) => { selectedItem.GoToSearchDatabase(); });  selectedItem is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use EventHandler *SelectedItemChanged* from *MvxBaseCollectionViewSource*

**View**

```
set.Bind(yourCollectionViewSource).For(s => s.SelectionChangedCommand).To(vm => vm.CollectionItemSelected);
```

**ViewModel**

```
public ICommand CollectionItemSelected => new MvxCommand<ItemViewModel>((selectedItem) => { });
```

Comment: Receive a null ref when trying to use selectedItem

Comment: I have found what I can do, is override TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt) - and go from there, which I suppose works.  But I am still curious as to why none of the bindings work